# Read Receipt Laravel Pusher

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, pusher

How can i call This method on My Project

```
class MessageDeliveredController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \App\Chat $chat
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke(Chat $chat)
    {
        $chat->status = 'Delivered';
        $chat->save();

        broadcast(new MessageDelivered($chat));
    }
}
```

I need Correct way

my routes are

```
Route::get('/chats', 'ChatController@index');
Route::get('/messages', 'ChatController@fetchAllMessages');
Route::post('/messages', 'ChatController@sendMessage');
Route::post('/chats', 'MessageDeliveredController');
```

Comment: Sending from client `POST` request to endpoint `/chats` code will be executed.

Comment: So u meant This is Correct Route  For this ?   Route::post('/chats', 'MessageDeliveredController');

Comment: Im sure  Yr Advise Is very Helpfull  but maybe  if the rout is correct  i have A problem in my vue js   again  i told u if u accepted the route  i guess my component is not correct oop in vue component   By the Way Really Thanks , I am Going To try again .